# How to handle error received from middleware in NEXT JS?

Tags: next.js, error-handling, authorization, middleware

Error returned from middleware doesn't trigger handling by Next JS and showing error UI from error.tsx or global-error.tsx file

Hi everyone.
I have an issue with errors handling in my Next JS project.
Let's take two routes from app. '/signin', here user must sign in to his account. I send query to the server, then receive token and save it to Cookies.
Other routes are protected by middleware, here it is:

```
export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const cookie = req.cookies.get('_bqat')?.value;
  const pathname = req.nextUrl.pathname;

  if (pathname === '/signin' || pathname === '/signup' || pathname === '/') {
    return NextResponse.next();
  } else {
    if (!cookie) {
      return new NextResponse(
        JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: 'You are not authorized' }),
        { status: 401, headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' } }
      );
    }
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

The logic is, middleware will check exact cookie created after successfull authorization. If it doesn't exist, it will not allow to go to the protected page and return error in response.

For handling any errors i've created usual error.tsx file, also tried global-error.tsx.
This error is shown in console. But it doesn't trigger handling by Next js and showing error ui from error.tsx file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFs5e.jpg)

Same situation even if i change returning Next Response to throwing new Error('any message'), error.tsx doesn't work:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls2tm.jpg)

Who had the same problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well a common approach would be to redirect the user to the login page with a return url in the query when he tries to access a protected page:

```
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const cookie = req.cookies.get("_bqat")?.value;
  const pathname = req.nextUrl.pathname;

  if (pathname === "/signin" || pathname === "/signup" || pathname === "/") {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  if (!cookie) {
    const returnTo = encodeURIComponent(req.nextUrl.pathname);
    const redirectURL = new URL(`/signin?returnTo=${returnTo}`, req.url);
    return NextResponse.redirect(redirectURL);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Upon successful login you then redirect the user to the return url if it was provided or back to the home page.

##### Security concerns

When using this approach it is wise to encrypt the return url and ensure it is same origin, so it is harder to steal the credentials, like a JWT that is returned. Here is an example of a url obfuscation class I wrote for a project in the past:

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import AES from "crypto-js/aes";
import UTF8 from "crypto-js/enc-utf8";

class URLObfuscator {
  private static instance: URLObfuscator | null = null;
  private secret = `${process.env.OBFUSCATOR_SECRET}`;

  private constructor() {}

  static init() {
    if (!this.instance) this.instance = new URLObfuscator();
    return this.instance;
  }

  private isSameOrigin(url: string): boolean {
    return !url.startsWith("http") || url.startsWith(process.env.HOST ?? "");
  }

  encode(url: string): string {
    if (!this.isSameOrigin(url)) {
      throw new Error(
        "Invalid URL, obfuscation is only available for same origin URL's."
      );
    }

    const iv = nanoid(16)?.toString();
    const encrypted = AES.encrypt(url, this.secret, { iv: iv as any });
    return `${btoa(iv)}.${encrypted.toString()}`;
  }

  decode(encoded: string): string {
    const enc_iv = encoded.split(".")[0];
    const iv = atob(enc_iv);
    const encrypted = encoded.replace(`${enc_iv}.`, "").replace(/ /g, "+");
    const decrypted = AES.decrypt(encrypted, this.secret, { iv: iv as any });
    return decrypted.toString(UTF8);
  }
}

export default URLObfuscator.init();
```